Angular test issue with snackbar and fakesync
When I test the angular material snackbar, set the duration to 3000ms and then try to test with fakeAsync after tick 3000, the snackbar still shown. How to make it auto close? Code

That StackBlitz has a lot of type errors... please fix them

Could you check again?

Thanks, looks better now. But when running the tests, the error is thrown before the tick is even being executed. It seems like the await loader.getHarness(MatSnackBarHarness) already fails.

Apparently, this is a known issue when opening a snack bar with a duration: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19290

Missed a statement ,added
